# BeautifulSoup web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape a website. When it returns the link it comes in as `/watch/411012/1/test.html` - how can I make it so it will return http://website.co.uk/watch/411012/1/test.html ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://website.co.uk") #add more sites
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('sports')): 
    print link['href']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
from urlparse import urljoin

base_url = "http://website.co.uk"
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('sports')): 
    print urljoin(base_url, link['href'])
```

Comment: how could i do this for multiple sites as in in one script.

Comment: @AlexMcbatman well, the base_url would be the site you are navigating to - `"http://website.co.uk"` in this case..see if it makes sense to create a separate question if you experience difficulties. Thanks.